# Math.random/floor with a function and onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

trying to write a function utilizing the math.floor/math.random JS objects that returns a number between 1 and 5 to the function and changes the color based on which number it was every time you click the button, like so:

[The result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzFU0.png)

[and my code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT7A6.png)

Every time I click the button the function just returns the last color in the function (darkslateblue), even if I set the "i = 5" to "i = 10" (unless I set it to 0). Is this because of my getRndInteger function, my colorFunction or my ?

Comment: please avoid screenshots of code. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the code that accomplishes-ish what I think you are trying to achieve. If I were doing it from scratch, I'd approach it a little different, but this gets you close and makes the logic work.

1. It's better if you copy/paste your code instead of screenshot.
2. Your random call needs to be in your color function for it to be called when button clicks.
3. you only had 5 color options for 6 possible random numbers (0-5).
4. for equality check in javascript you use "==" or "===", not "="
5. don't forget the trailing () when calling Math.random

Anyway, a rough idea of the code is below.

```
<div id="banner">Color Banner</div>
<button id="button" onclick="colorFunction()">Change Color</button>
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("banner");
    function getRndInteger(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;  
    }
    function colorFunction() {   
    var i = getRndInteger(0, 6);
    if (i == 0) {
        x.style.backgroundColor = "teal";
        x.innerHTML = i;
    }
    if (i == 1) {
        x.style.backgroundColor = "goldenrod";
        x.innerHTML = i;
    }
    if (i == 2) {
        x.style.backgroundColor = "darkolivegreen";
        x.innerHTML = i;
    }
    if (i == 3) {
        x.style.backgroundColor = "darkslategrey";
        x.innerHTML = i;
    }
    if (i == 4) {
        x.style.backgroundColor = "darkslateblue";
        x.innerHTML = i;
    }
    if (i == 5) {
        x.style.backgroundColor = "maroon";
        x.innerHTML = i;
    }
   }
</script>
```

or, instead of if-else statements, you could use a switch:

```
<div id="banner">Color Banner</div>
<button id="button" onclick="colorFunction()">Change Color</button>

<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("banner");

    function getRndInteger(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    }

    function colorFunction() {

        var i = getRndInteger(0, 6);

        x.innerHTML = i;

        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                x.style.backgroundColor = "teal";
                break;
            case 1:
                x.style.backgroundColor = "goldenrod";
                break;
            case 2:
                x.style.backgroundColor = "darkolivegreen";
                break;
            case 3:
                x.style.backgroundColor = "darkgrey";
                break;
            case 4:
                x.style.backgroundColor = "darkslateblue";
                break;
            case 5:
                x.style.backgroundColor = "maroon";
                break;
        }
    }
</script>
```